# Convert from 'QChar' to 'wchar_t'

Tags: c++, qt, qchar

I need to pass a QChar to a function that expects a `wchar_t`:

```
void myFunc(wchar_t wch);
```

Trying to just pass the `QChar` fails with an error:

```
error: C2664: 'myFunc' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QChar' to 'wchar_t'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer even while I was asking the question, I needed to use [QChar::unicode()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qchar.html#unicode-2).

```
wchar_t wch = qch.unicode();
```

Comment: @egur Btw I still wasted a good 20 minutes, because it was totally unsearchable - it's declaration is `ushort unicode()`. Had it been `wchar_t toWChar()`, it would have been a non-issue. I have the habit of doing quick searches using `Ctrl+F` or just the intellisense, instead of reading every function of the class.